# Python urllib - Spurious Incomming Packet Loss in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, urllib, connection-timeout

I have a strange issue using Python 3 and urllib...

I have a Python application which runs as mulitple processes (about 5 to 8 instances) started using Popen.

At regular intervals, these processes make a connection to a IP Camera to try and fetch an image.

This works perfectly using one camera, but starting with 4 Cameras, I get random connections errors. All cameras are connected to a set of PoE switches. I already moved the cameras between the switches to see if it would have an impact on the errors, but the errors are mostly the same, so I does not to appear to be hardware related.

Although the error does not seem to originate from the camera (alone it works without a flaw), the number of errors is directly dependent of the camera. I mean once there are more than 3 or 4 cameras in parallel, errors start to occur and the count of errors is related to the camera... Fro example Camera #1 would fail on 20% of the requests, Cam#2 on 4%, Cam#3 on 5%, and this does not change regardless which cameras are connected.

If I don't add a timeout, It may fail after a few seconds up to full days with various errors among: WinError 10060 10061 and 10054

Note that all processes are starting a request almost simultaneously. But I cannot imagine that this is the root cause of the error as 8 connections requests are not much!!!

When I looked at the Wireshark trace I found that it seems that the incoming packets are somehow lost when an error occurs. I don't believe this is an error of the cameras, as they work when the PC accesses only one camera at a time, and the missing message is from the camera...

It is like if the message was somewhere in a buffer but unnoticed until urllib times out.

**This is a normal connection:**

[image]

**This is if it fails:**

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
#
# Read the sensor data
#
def _ReadSensor(self):

    command = 'http://{0}/record/current.jpg'.format(self.link_ip)

    # Time metering
    tic = time.time()

    # Read camera
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(command, timeout=self._read_timeout)

    except Exception as e:
        duration1 = time.time() -  tic
        raise Exception("Failure to read image from camera \'{0}\' @ {1} ({2}s until exception)...\n{3}".format(self.sensor_name, self.link_ip, duration1, e))

    else:

        # Return response
        try:
            duration2 = time.time() -  tic
            return response.read()

        except Exception as e:
            duration3 = time.time() -  tic
            raise Exception("Failure to read from connection from camera \'{0}\' @ {1} ({2}s until read, {3}s until exception)...\n{4}".format(self.sensor_name, self.link_ip, duration2, duration3, e))

        finally:
            response.close()
```

Again: the code is run from independent processes started with Popen. the exception thrown is the first one ("Failure to read image from ...").

Of course I do also get other errors from time to time in other locations, but this is the one happening 99% of the time.

These is also a code to set properties of the camera, which fails from time to time, but works most of the time. (the code is Reading the Cam -> Setting the Cam -> Reading the Cam -> Setting the Cam -> and so on...)

```
    # Build command string
    command = "http://{0}/control/control?set&{1}".format(self.link_ip, command_string)

    # Time metering
    tic = time.time()

    # Send command and ensure it is closed
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(command, timeout=self._write_timeout)            

    except Exception as e:
        duration = time.time() -  tic
        raise Exception("Failed to send a command to the camera \'{0}\' @ {1} ({2}s until exception)...\n{3}".format(self.sensor_name, self.link_ip, duration, e))

    else:
        response.close()
```

If you need more information let me know! Thanks!!!